# Circle in circle with padding css

Tags: css

I have a code

```css
 h2:before {
            display: block;
            content: "";
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background: #F67280;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        
  }
```

```html
<div>

<h2>Visibilty hidden</h2>

</div>
```

I need with `:before` do circle black in circle red with moving black circle how in this screen:

[image]

How I can do it? Please help resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: some sort of `box-shadow` would seem to be in order...

Comment: Have you tried just setting `position` and `top`/`left` properties? It would be nice to see some effort at resolving the issue yourself...

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 pseudo elements - one for the pink and the other for the border

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
}

h2:before,
h2:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

h2:before {
  background: #F67280;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h2:after {
  border-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <h2>Visibilty hidden</h2>

</div>
```